# RSA encrypt string with pkcs1 padding in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, rsa

I encrypted string with rsa and pkcs1 padding in .NET Standard 2.0 successfully!

```
namespace core20
{
    public class Tests
    {
        private string PublicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC4xKeUgQ+Aoz7TLfAfs9+paePb
5KIofVthEopwrXFkp8OCeocaTHt9ICjTT2QeJh6cZaDaArfZ873GPUn00eOIZ7Ae
+TiA2BKHbCvloW3w5Lnqm70iSsUi5Fmu9/2+68GZRH9L7Mlh8cFksCicW2Y2W2uM
GKl64GDcIq3au+aqJQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var util = new RsaPkcs1Util(Encoding.UTF8, PublicKey);
            var messageAfterEncrypted = util.Encrypt("Message will be encrypted", RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
            Assert.NotNull(messageAfterEncrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to encrypted with the same rule (RSA + pkcs1 padding) in .NET Framework 4.0.

This is a successful example https://github.com/qianfeiqianlan/cshap-encrypted-example/blob/master/core20/encryption-test.cs

And I don't know what the correct way is in [.NET Framework 4.0](https://github.com/qianfeiqianlan/cshap-encrypted-example/blob/master/Framework40/encryption-test.cs)

Comment: You can find examples in the MS documentation. e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.0